# How give azure machine learning dataset path in an inference script?

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using azureml sdk in Azure Databricks.

When I write the script for inference model (%%writefile script.py) in a databricks cell,
I try to load a .bin file that I loaded in Azure Machine Learning Datasets.

I would like to do this in the script.py:

```
fasttext.load_model(azuremldatasetpath)
```

How can I do to give good dataset path of my .bin file in azuremldatasetpath variable ? (Without calling workspace in the script).

Something like:

```
dataset_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('AZUREML_MODEL_DIR'), 'file.bin')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your model name with the [Model.get_model_path()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-core-model-model-get-model-path) method to retrieve the path of the model file or files on the local file system. If you register a folder or a collection of files, this API returns the path of the directory that contains those files.

More info you may want to refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-advanced-entry-script#azureml_model_dir